# Is there a standard way of enumerating allocated heap blocks in Linux?

Tags: linux, heap-memory, enumerate

In windows, I've used Heap32ListFirst / Heap32ListNext to iterate over the heaps list, and then for each heap I'd use Heap32First / Heap32Next to get every block.

Is there an equivalent way of doing so in Linux, glibc or otherwise? I couldn't find any functions to walk the heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sbrk(0)` to get the "program break" pointer, which is effectively the "end" of the heap.  Walking it, however, requires knowing implementation details of your particular `malloc()`.  So no, there is not really a standard way of doing what you're asking.

See also: [How to iterate all malloc chunks (glibc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37988364/how-to-iterate-all-malloc-chunks-glibc)